# (neo)vim coc - go-to-definition for html css

Tags: html, css, vim, neovim, go-to-definition

I was looking for a solution but never found a good one. Does anyone use COC for html css. How to go to definition in css file from class or ID in html file? Thanks for any help!

Comment: try css peek extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pranaygp.vscode-css-peek

Comment: Thank you, I actualy used that extension. But is just for VS Code. I need same exact thing for Vim (neovim).

Comment: Also consider the [vi.se] Stack Exchange for questions on Vim.

Answer (score -1):

"------- web html ------------

```
if count(g:bundle_groups, 'html')

    "Plugin 'othree/html5.vim'
    " html css
    Plugin 'mattn/emmet-vim'

endif
```

"------- web css ------------

```
if count(g:bundle_groups, 'css')

endif
```